# Android || Error parsing XML, not well formed || Manifest.xml file

Tags: android, debugging, android-layout

I am having trouble finding why my syntax is wrong in the manfest.xml file.  It is probably something simple so it would be appreciated it you guys helped real quick.  I must be missing a key syntax issue, as I have tried to fiddle with it and got nowhere so far.  I had these xml files working earlier but randomly they deleted themselves.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidassignment2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.Startup"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>      

        <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1" 
        </activity>

   <activity
       android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1"
        </activity>

  <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1"
        </activity>


  <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1"
        </activity>


  <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_4"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1"
        </activity>

  <Activity
        android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_5"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1"
        </Activity>



    </application>






</manifest>
```

Comment: This question is too localized.  It's unlikely to help any future visitors.

Comment: I recommend getting an interactive development environment (IDE) like Android Studio that provides autoformatting and/or error checking.  It's great for spotting/fixing syntax errors like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.androidassignment2"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.Startup"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_5"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a ">" in all your activity declarations after the first one.

Comment: I copied above posters code, and was able to successfully run the application.  Must have missed something else small as well.

Comment: In that case you should mark that answer as the correct answer (use the checkmark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

One of the activity tags is written wrongly as `<Activity>,` thats why you were facing the error. It should be `<activity>`

Comment: ah yea that was the other problem, thanks for bringing that to my attention for the future :p